# Robot framework ensure unique test case name

Tags: python, robotframework

I am making a large Robot Framework test suite, with lots of test cases. I would like, in my suite setup line, to go through each of the test case names, and make sure none of them are the same. Is this possible? Or maybe an api that I can use from Python to read the .robot file's test cases and get their names?

Comment: What do you plan to do if you find a duplicate name? Robot already gives you a warning about that.

Comment: Also, if you have two separate robot files, and each has a test of the same name, do you consider those duplicates? Or are you only looking for duplicates within each file?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I am looking only for duplicates within one file. I just want the test suite to fail if it detects duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fail an entire suite if it has any duplicate test names, you could create a library that acts as a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) so that it can get a list of test names. You can then write a keyword that causes a failure if the list of tests has a duplicate test name in it.

It might look something like this:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class DuplicateListener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    def fail_if_suite_has_duplicate_test_names(self):
        dupes = []
        suites = [test.name for test in self.current_suite.tests]
        while suites:
            test = suites.pop()
            if test in suites:
                dupes.append(test)
        if dupes:
            duplicates = ", ".join(sorted(dupes))
            raise Exception(f"Suite has duplicate test names: {duplicates}")

    def _start_suite(self, data, suite):
        self.current_suite = data
```

You can call the keyword from a suite setup

```
*** Settings ***
Library        DuplicateListener.py
Suite Setup    Fail if suite has duplicate test names

*** Test cases ***
Example 1
    log  hello, world

Example 1
    log  a duplicate test name
```

The output would look something like this:

```
$ robot example.robot 
==============================================================================
Example                                                                       
==============================================================================
Example 1                                                             | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Suite has duplicate test names: Example 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ WARN ] Multiple test cases with name 'Example 1' executed in test suite 'Example'.
Example 1                                                             | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Suite has duplicate test names: Example 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example                                                               | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
Suite has duplicate test names: Example 1

2 tests, 0 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
```